# Moving data from controller to res.render

Tags: node.js, express, controller

I am wondering how I can take and do something like `return res.status(400).json({message: 'This is my message'})` in a controller/middleware then I want to be able to in a callback or another custom controller do `res.render('test', {message})` where the `message` comes from my controller above. I am using EJS for my view engine which is where the `{message}` part comes from.

I have looked around online and on SO but have yet to find a good explanation of how to properly do this. I know that without the callback res.render part I can have my API work properly and returns the correct JSON to postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can pass data from a *middleware* to a *handler* by putting the data in the `req` object. The middleware is defined as a function like `(req, res, next) => { // Do stuff here}`. Inside that you can do `req.somePayloadIWantToPass = {hello: 'world'};`
- In your case, passing the information might look like this

---

```
const app = require("express")();
const port = 3000;

// Your middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const payload = { message: "this is my message", statusCode: 400 };
  req.payload = payload;
  next();
});

// Your request handler
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const { message, statusCode } = req.payload;
  res.status(statusCode).render({ message });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

## Notes

- You can't use `send` multiple times for a certain request
- Here we defined `payload` as a hard-coded variable, but you can define a certain logic to derive it from your request's body or parameters

Comment: Okay thanks, that kind of confirms what I had already thought. My only issue with that way is while I want to be able to access the data with EJS I also need it to return to my API call so that if I use something like postman it will give back the raw json.

Comment: You can still return different responses (JSON or HTML) based on the header `Content-Type` to which you can assign your target response format. Then you handle the different headers in your handler

Comment: Thanks will give that a try

Comment: My pleasure! If this answers your question, don't forget to mark it as answered. Cheers